# PHP date and setlocale do not always work

Tags: php, apache, nginx, strftime, setlocale

After generating the required locale on our development server and using `setlocale` to provide PHP with the locale to use the dates formatted with `strftime` would appear fully translated, as expected.

After reloading the page however, the dates were shown in the server's default locale: `en_US`. Reloading the pages multiple times resulted in almost a 50/50 chance of the dates being translated. Weird. What is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that both *Apache* and *Nginx* webservers need to be restarted after having locales generated for them to be able to use them without problems.

Either use `service apache2 restart` or `service nginx restart` to fix the problem. In some cases the entire server might need a restart to fix the problem.

Thanks to [Helmut Strasser's blog post](http://iblog.ikarius.net/index.php/2014/01/21/php-setlocale-works-sometimes/) we were able to identify the problem.

Comment: This helped me solve this. php-fpm also has to be restarted in my case, which was the missing link.